# Action buttons are shown in all fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have included a menu in my fragment.
But when going to other fragments(not overriding menu) in my viewpager the actions buttons remains the same (with all the actions) even when setting setHasOptionsMenu(false).

Anyone knows how to disable action buttons in other fragments or you need to inflate an empty menu in each fragment ?

Thanks in advance

This is my code (in fragment) :

```
@Override

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setHasOptionsMenu` from the `Fragment` `onCreateView` , to tell the `Activity` that the Fragment has Option Menu. So that the `onCreateOptionsMenu` will be called.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return row;
}
```

And, In `onCreateOptionsMenu` , just clear the menu items

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: But it is not working after opening a DialogFragment.