# Android - Switching between fragments; Menu Item problems

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, menu

My application uses fragments, action bar, and a navigation drawer.  When I switch between fragments my menu items become broken and no longer function.  I have tried a variety of things that may fix the problem but to no avail.

In my Fragment `onCreate` I have `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`.

This is my `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d("Log", "Inflating Menu");
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.blank, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This is my simple `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mySearch:
            Log.d("Log", "Implementing Search Method");
            search();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_settings:
            //do something
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In each Fragment's menu I use `menu.Clear();` to prevent a pile up of Menu Items while switching between Fragments.  The menu runs the selected function just fine when the Fragment is selected for the first time, but after switching to another Fragment and back again Menu Item clicks do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is your clearing the menu and doing inflate menu again.

Remove the line

```
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.blank, menu);
```

Instead you need to just clear the menu in onCreateOptionsMenu() of Fragment , so that the menu will not be shown for that speciifc fragment , and will show for other fragment.

Also you need to inflate the menu only in `Activity`  `onCreateOptionsMenu`  which is common to all the fragment

Also see my answer here. [Action buttons are shown in all fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177213/action-buttons-are-shown-in-all-fragments)

Comment: Thistle does not make much sense to me. You are telling him to not inflate the menu in the Fragment but only clear it correct and only load the menu from the activity? Then what do we do about separate menu items that should be associated with certain fragments and not others?

Comment: Clear only if you need to hide, if different menu item for fragment then he need to inflate.

Comment: Yes this answer doesn't make any sense at all. Google specifically allowed for fragments to contribute options menus. If this shouldn't be done then evidence needs to be provide for why this is so.